# Annotation in Python with Python keywords?

Tags: python

I want to have a type annotation for a backend API using FastAPI, and one of my response name is `from`. It causes the `SyntaxError` when I try to run it, and I wanted to know if there's a way to define names as same as some Python keywords' annotation. My code is below:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Dict, Optional, List


class PicResultsModel(BaseModel):
    host: str
    title: str
    url: str


class PicModel(BaseModel):
    results: List[PicResultsModel]
    total: int


class WebResultsModel(BaseModel):
    des: str
    from: str   # <---

class WebModel(BaseModel):
    results: List[WebResultsModel]
    total: int
```

Comment: Do not use keywords as an identifier. The parser won't handle it and you'll confuse yourself and others in the future.

Comment: Oh.. OK. I got that. I'll change that to another name later. Thanks!

Comment: You can use an alias. `from pydantic import BaseModel, Field`. Them define your property as `from_: str = Field(..., alias="from")`. This will allow your JSON response to have the field name "from" but in your application code you refer to it as *from_*.

Comment: Thanks guys! I've changed the name from `from` to `origin` now.